# Transaction unconfirmed after almost 2 day! Help!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I tried to send a bitcoin transfer Wednesday evening and it is still unconfirmed. It says "fees 0" but I have my block chain account set to "use recommended fee" by default. Can anyone help me get this confirmed? If greatly appreciate it!

Here it is: https://blockchain.info/tx/f054dbba378cea1b82168214cf28771f60c7cc30be0963b0b38498c7a0ec9166

Comment: Are you using the blockchain.info wallet?

Comment: Yes, I am. Is that bad?

Comment: @Brandon Not really. It is bad that one of the inputs to the transaction is unconfirmed, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious reasons why your tx remains unconfirmed:

1. You have not included the recommended tx fee (that's probably your wallet's fault, unless you've manually overridden its default settings)
2. You are spending an unconfirmed output: https://blockchain.info/tx-index/81648421/0 (also an insufficient tx fee issue). Unless this output gets confirmed, the tx above will never get any confirmations.

Most probably the tx will get invalidated by the network soon and the "spent" funds will return to your wallet.

In the meantime I would suggest you to be careful with spending unconfirmed outputs (there is an option to disable the spending of unconfirmed outputs in the bitcoin-core client) and avoid it whenever it's possible. Also, including the appropriate fee will make your tx much more likely to get confirmed soon by the network.

Answer (score 1):

I've pushed this transaction. It will be confirmed soon (I hope in an hour).
Next time do not spend unconfirmed outputs

Comment: ok, it confirmed :)

Comment: Oh wow thank you. I didn't know there was an unconfirmed output! Please give me a bitcoin address for you so I can send you a tip or something, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you. I do not collect donations and tips. I did it because I am able to do it :) Isn't it funny?

Comment: I have the same problem, can you please tell me how you did @amaclin